# Extract string from email - SharePoint out of box workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, out-of-the-box

I am using out-of-box SharePoint 2010 workflows. I have an email address stored in a variable, e.g. abc.xyz@domain.com. I want to extract the string after '@' and before following '.', i.e. 'domain' in this case. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you specially the regular expression bit.

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/60840

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it like this:

- Store email id of the submitter in a variable
- Copy 10 characters ('domain.com' in this case) from the end of the variable string and store it in variable2
- Copy 6 characters (domain) from the start of variable2